# ECMAScript Modules (import / export) @ Node.js (currently @ v13.0.1)

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

## ECMAScript Modules (import / export) @ Node.js (currently @ v13.0.1)

1. When will it be supported to natively use:

- ECMAScript Modules (import / export) without the .mjs extension (if ever)
- Exec it without the `--experimental-modules` flag
- Not using the [**esm**](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) npm package

2. Which impact will it have on developing npm packages (currently and in the future)?
3. What would be the impact of this approach while developing using some of existent framework (ex: ExpressJS, Loopback, etc...)

---

##### class.mjs

```
'use strict'

export class TryMe{
  
  constructor(a, b){
    this.sum = a+b
    this.mutiply = a*b
  }

  getSum(){
    console.log(this.sum)
  }

  getMultiply(){
    console.log(this.mutiply)
  }

}
```

##### main.mjs

```
'use strict'
import { TryMe } from './class.mjs'

const tryme = new TryMe(1, 2)
tryme.getMultiply()
```

---

All the feedback, clarifications and updates to this will be extremely welcome!

[**Source GitHub Gist**](https://gist.github.com/undertuga/d9a71be854b52855b2051fc1d381447b)

Comment: This question is far too broad to be answerable on StackOverflow. For when native support will come, it's best to follow the relevant Github issues.

Comment: Just to add a bit to what @Bergi correctly said, there is also the issue that your question is asking us to predict future trends.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your feedback! I truly appreciate it.

But indeed there's a "more or less" defined timeline for the nº1 to happen, being v14 @ April 2020 (kinda replying to what Aluan Haddad said, no trend predictions in here...) 

That's mainly because, being ES the standard, sooner or later, and offcourse, depending on all the many stakeholders and many different platforms involved (Node.js, npm, browsers, JS engines, TypeScript, TC39, etc.) it will be natively supported. 

The point was to try to bring up some discution and clarifications on the impacts of this implementation...

Comment: ... and i'm entirely  open to suggestion to where this topic should be raised and discussed, if it's engagement is not proper to do on StackOverflow. Kindly request opinions and suggestions. Also for reference, i would like to leave this link [ECMAScript modules in Node.js: the new plan](https://2ality.com/2018/12/nodejs-esm-phases.html) that i found while researching regarding this topic. Thank you all for your opinion and feedback.

Comment: @undertuga I guess [esdiscuss](https://esdiscuss.org/), [esdiscourse](https://es.discourse.group/), twitter, medium, or anyone's blog are better venues for discussion